# Initialize Spring logging only in JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot, testing

I have a test for code that integrates with third-party code that logs noisily. I've added the following to my Spring Boot configuration:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    com.thirdparty.Noisy: "off"
```

This has disabled the logging as expected when running the Spring Boot application, but I would like to disable the logging in my automated tests as well. I would also like to avoid booting everything with `@SpringBootTest`. Is there a way to load *only* Spring Boot's logging system for the duration of a test?

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring Boot's [LoggingSystem](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystem.html) abstraction can do what you want:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.logging.LogLevel;
import org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem;

class ExampleTest {

  @BeforeAll
  static void disableNoisyLogging() {
    LoggingSystem loggingSystem = LoggingSystem.get(ExampleTest.class.getClassLoader());
    loggingSystem.setLogLevel("com.thirdparty.Noisy", LogLevel.OFF);
  }

  @Test
  void someTest() {
    // ...
  }
}
```